# Node.js Module plugins

Tags: javascript, node.js

I was hoping to find out what the best practices are for writing Node.js modules, specifically for the type of javascript pattern to follow for code separation.

One style I've been using, is this:

```
var Something;

Something = (function() {

    function Something() {
    }

    Something.prototype.some = function() {

    }

    return Something;

})();

module.exports = Something;
```

Another style would be :

```
module.exports = {
 item: "one",
 some: function() {

 },
 another: function() {

 }
}
```

Is there any reason why the second method would not be advised, in node.js? or is there another format that would be preferred and what would the advantages be?

Thank you!

Comment: There is no reason to encapsulate your `Something` constructor inside an anonymous function. The purpose of anonymous functions used this way is to prevent namespace polution, but modules in Node are already confined to their own namespaces.

Comment: Thanks, good tip, will remove that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You run into issues using the 'this' keyword.  Which you have to use instead of 'Something'.  So Something.some() you can run... But if you wanted to run that on the bottom, you'd have to run this.run().  The scope of this changes within other functions and can get messy.

Answer (score 1):

There are several variants including assigning properties directly to `exports`, assigning a new object literal to `module.exports` and a few others. For the most part they are just syntax sugar or syntax alternatives that accomplish exactly the same thing. My personal preference is to leave as much of my code as possible unpolluted pure JS, and keep the CommonJS idioms separate. So I do:

```
function myFunction() {

}

var MY_STRING = "Forty-two";


module.exports = {
    myFunction: myFunction,
    MY_STRING: MY_STRING
};
```

It's a bit boilerplate-y and prone to maintenance mistakes, but I prefer it to the alternatives as I really dislike putting the CommonJS module level names (module, exports) sprinkled throughout my code. CoffeeScript makes the last part easier since you can just do:

```
module.exports = {
    myFunction
    MY_STRING
}
```